# I want to load a dictionary from a pickled dat file but the issue is that the first time I try to load it the pickled dictionary does not exist

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I am a GCSE student and have been set a problem that requires me to save student name and test scores to a file for later retrieval and manipulation.

I have decided to store the data in a dictionary which I will pickle and retrieve as required.I know how to pickle a dictionary and retrieve a previously pickled dictionary.

The problem I have only occurs the first time the program is run as the dat file has not yet been created.

The code below opens the existing Dat file and writes the latest student name and score to the dictionary held in the file.

```
f = open("class1.dat","ab+")
class1 = pickle.load(f)
class1[Name]=Score
pickle.dump(class1,f)
f.close
```

The problem is that this works once the first score has been saved to the Dat file but I get this error message the first time the program is run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Latest_Version.py", line 61, in <module>
    class1 = pickle.load(f)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

I realise that this is because the dat file does not yet exist.

What code would check to see if the Dat file existed first?

If you can help please keep it very simple as my knowledge is limited.

Comment: Run `f.seek(0)` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because you do not have data in your pickle file to start off with. You need to run a check to see if you have data to load to start off with. So, you can throw your code in a try/except to check if you can load the data. If you can't, write initial data (empty data) to the pickle file.

Furthermore, pay attention to explicitly setting reading and writing to the file.

```
import pickle

class1 = {}
try:
    class1 = pickle.load(open("my_stuff.pkl", "rb"))
    print(class1)
    class1['bob'] = 123
    pickle.dump(class1, open("my_stuff.pkl", "wb"))
except:
    pickle.dump(class1, open("my_stuff.pkl", "wb"))
```

So, what happens here is that you first declare an empty dictionary, then you try to load the contents. If it fails, it will fall in to the `except`, dump the empty data. So the next time you come in, it will then load successfully, you can write your data, and then dump the pickle.

Comment: It doesn't give an `IOError`; it gives `EOFError`.  I believe the problem is that he opens the file with `'a'`, and does not seek to the beginning.

Comment: idjaw where would I type

    from os.path import isfile

would it be at the start of the program like

    import pickle

Is it calling a function?

Comment: @PythonNewb made an update. Look at the solution again.

Comment: @PythonNewb My new solution does not require that. I updated my solution. Refresh your page.

Comment: @PythonNewb Made another change. This solution works. You need to be explicit about your read and write.

Comment: That solution looks perfect. I notice that you use .pkl rather than .dat for the file. Was there a reason for that?

Comment: @PythonNewb . I like to use pkl to indicate to myself it is a pickle file. It is more convention than anything. Feel free to do whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: I hope this is not becoming boring for you all but i have ran the above code and got the following error.   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/import_class1_pickled_file.py", line 13, in <module>
    f.close()
NameError: name 'f' is not defined.

I assume that this is because the file does not currently exist. Is that right?

Comment: @PythonNewb Oh good catch. That f.close() should not be there.